# Examining a old bedikah cloth

Tags: halacha, see-sight-vision-blind, niddah, color, blood

AFAIK the psak on a bedikah cloth depends on the colour of the stain. Any shade of red indicates nidda, other colours, including brown, are okay.

Doesn't blood turn from red to brown when it dries? That would imply you have to see the cloth very soon after the bedikah is made to decide accurately.

Is this a practical consideration for bedikahs?

Comment: Not everyone agrees brown is ok.

Comment: See Taz and Bach YD 188

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a Bach that discusses fresh wet bedikos vs dry ones . Noone seems to care about his concern and the apprenticeship is on dry bedikos so people are trained to recognize their halachic status in that state. 
At some point though the color does change and competent Rabbis will no longer pasken on them. But interestingly enough the nida blood does not turn brown as quickly as other blood. This should not be used as a practical proof to tamei vs tahor blood, but it is a general observation.

Source is my inspection teachers.